# C# Scripting with access to objects within application

Tags: c#

Hello and still happy Ney Year

I would like to ask you for initial aid. My goal is to write a parser (e.g. source file is a bmecat-xml file and target is an Excel-file) that is dynamic and flexible enough to handle data-conversion even when sourcefile-content changes or user would require additional transformation of data.

I wrote the first part of the parser which loads data from the source-bmecat-file into corresponding classes. The class structure is exposed to the user (by reflection) and the user can map source-fields to target fields.

Where I get stuck is at the moment, when additional logic / conversion needs to be incorporated.
I think Scripting would help me to solve this. the mapping data (source field to target field) could contain an additional script that would be executed dynamically (and hence must have access to application data, especially classes which hold sourcefile and targetfile data).

It would be really great if you could point me to the right direction, to a point, where I can start from.

Thank you very much!

sample-code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ScriptingDemoProject
{
    class DataClass
    {
        TargetData target;
        SourceData source;
        MappingData map;

        public DataClass()
        {
            target = new TargetData();
            source = new SourceData();
            map = new MappingData();

            // generate sample data
            GenerateData();

            // copy source data to target data
            ExecuteMapping();
        }

        public TargetData TargetDataInfo
        { get { return target; } }
        public SourceData SourceDataInfo
        { get { return source; } }
        public MappingData MappingDataInfo
        { get { return map; } }

        private void GenerateData()
        {
            // add sourcedata
            source.Header.DefaultLanguage = "deu";
            source.RecipientID = "recipient...";
            source.SenderID = "sender...";
            SourceItem item = new SourceItem();
            item.ItemID = "Item1";
            item.ItemNames.AddRange( new List<SourceItemName>() {
                new SourceItemName { ItemName = "Item1NameGerman", Languauge = "deu" },
                new SourceItemName { ItemName = "Item1NameFrench", Languauge = "fra" }
            });
            source.Items.Add(item);

            // add targetdata
            target.AddRec(new List<TargetField>()
            {
                new TargetField { ColumnID=0, FieldName="ItemNo", FieldValue="Item1"},
                new TargetField { ColumnID=1, FieldName="DescrGerman", FieldValue=""},
                new TargetField { ColumnID=2, FieldName="DescrFrench", FieldValue=""}
            });
            target.AddRec(new List<TargetField>()
            {
                new TargetField { ColumnID=0, FieldName="ItemNo", FieldValue="Item2"},
                new TargetField { ColumnID=1, FieldName="DescrGerman", FieldValue=""},
                new TargetField { ColumnID=2, FieldName="DescrFrench", FieldValue=""}
            });

            // add mappinginstructions
            map.TargetKeyFieldIndex = 0;
            map.MappingFieldInfo.AddRange(new List<MappingFields>() {
                new MappingFields { SourceFieldMapping="ItemName", TargetFieldMapping=1, ScriptMapping=@"... where Language=""ger""" },
                new MappingFields { SourceFieldMapping="ItemName", TargetFieldMapping=2, ScriptMapping=@"... where Language=""fra""" }
            });

            // get properties, e.g.
            var pInfo = source.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);


        }

        private void ExecuteMapping()
        {
            // get target records
            foreach (var targetRec in TargetDataInfo.TargetRecords)
            {
                // get key field value
                string itemNo = targetRec.Where(x => x.ColumnID == map.TargetKeyFieldIndex).FirstOrDefault().FieldValue;

                // get source item
                SourceItem srcItem = SourceDataInfo.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == itemNo).FirstOrDefault();
                if (srcItem == null)
                    continue;

                // get mapping instructions
                foreach (var mapInstruction in map.MappingFieldInfo)
                {

                    // i'd like to have two options 
                    // option 1: use script 
                    // option 2: use reflection

                    // option 1: script
                    // script will be executed at runtime and gets value from srcItem and sets value in targetRec
                    string script = mapInstruction.ScriptMapping;
                    // script would contain / execute the following statements:
                    TargetField field = targetRec.Where(x => x.ColumnID == mapInstruction.TargetFieldMapping).FirstOrDefault();
                    field.FieldValue = srcItem.ItemNames.Where(x => x.Languauge == "deu").FirstOrDefault().ItemName;

                    // option 2: get value by reflection
                    // e.g.
                    // though don't know how to handle List<Class> 
                    PropertyInfo pi = SourceDataInfo.GetType().GetProperty("SenderID");
                    object val = pi.GetValue(SourceDataInfo, null);
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class MappingData
    {
        List<MappingFields> mappingFields;

        public MappingData ()
        {
            mappingFields = new List<MappingFields>();
        }
        public int TargetKeyFieldIndex { get; set; }
        public List<MappingFields> MappingFieldInfo
        { get { return mappingFields; } }
    }

    public class MappingFields
    {
        public string SourceFieldMapping { get; set; }
        public int TargetFieldMapping { get; set; }
        public string ScriptMapping { get; set; }
    }

    public class TargetData
    {
        private List<List<TargetField>> targetRecords;

        public TargetData()
        {
            targetRecords = new List<List<TargetField>>();
        }

        public List<List<TargetField>> TargetRecords
        { get { return targetRecords; } }

        public void AddRec(List<TargetField> TargetFields)
        {
            targetRecords.Add(TargetFields);
        }
    }

    public class TargetField
    {
        public string FieldName
        { get; set; }
        public int ColumnID
        { get; set; }
        public string FieldValue
        { get; set; }

    }

    public class SourceData
    {
        private List<SourceItem> sourceItems;
        private SourceHeader sourceHeader;

        public SourceData()
        {
            sourceHeader = new SourceHeader();
            sourceItems = new List<SourceItem>();
        }

        public SourceHeader Header
        { get { return sourceHeader; } }
        public List<SourceItem> Items
        { get { return sourceItems; } }
        public string SenderID
        { get; set; }
        public string RecipientID
        { get; set; }

    }
    public class SourceHeader
    {
        public string DefaultLanguage
        { get; set; }
    }
    public class SourceItem
    {
        private List<SourceItemName> itemNames;

        public SourceItem()
        {
            itemNames = new List<SourceItemName>();
        }

        public string ItemID
        { get; set; }
        public List<SourceItemName> ItemNames
        { get { return itemNames; } }
        public SourceItemName GetNameByLang(string Lang)
        {
            return itemNames.Where(x => x.Languauge == Lang).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
    public class SourceItemName
    {
        public string ItemName
        { get; set; }
        public string Languauge
        { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at Roslyn https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: Yes, I did, Thx! could not find the right example yet, though

Comment: Are there any tutorials on how to access application data within scripts? Thx!

Comment: Can you flesh out your question a bit more with regards to what you're attempting - do you have code you can show ?

Comment: added a sample, ty!

Comment: Define an interface (or more than one) with methods you want to call, use it in your code and create some kind of configuration which decides which object should be created for which used interface. Then simply create C# classes who implement your interface(s) and compile them at runtime and call the methods. :) You could search for c# plugin system.

Comment: hi user743414 
an interesting approach - i'm sure i will make us of it in other Projects. for this one, i think i'd rather go for Scripting. thx!

Comment: See if this helps also: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/04/26/wccsp_dlr-extensibility.aspx

Comment: @jake A C# PluginSystem is nothing more than pre compiled C# scripts. 8) You could also create C# files which then will be compiled and used at runtime. But in general it's the same.